# flutter app stuck on white blank screen and then losses device connection

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, android-emulator

I am unable to launch a flutter, both on mobile and on android emulator. I've checked all other questions similar to mine, but the answers provided could not help solve this issue. Who else has encountered something like this and what fix worked for you? The file is pretty large, over 5k lines of code, I could have just paste it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible cause of this occurrence is the presence of an infinite loop anywhere in your code. Once flutter encounters any infinite loop while preparing your app state, it gets stuck on executing this and the device/emulator connection timeout, hence connection lost. Place a print statement in all loops in code concerned with the homepage of your app, it's one of the stress free way to detect the culprit loop.